# Optional slash in url of restfull controller

Tags: rest, angularjs

Is there a way to dynamically add a slash to your rest url?
e.g. I want to be able to generate the following rest urls in one resource.

```
rest/blogpost/1
rest/blogpost/1/allInfo
```

given the resource below, i can achieve my first url. But is there a way to make the second url with /allInfo (optional in same lResource).

```
lResource = $resource("../rest/blogpost/:blogId", {
```

Or do I need a second resource like this?

```
lResource = $resource("../rest/blogpost/:blogId/allInfo", {
```

The problem with the second $resource is that allInfo isn't optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your second argument optional using the `:` you can make it to work.

```
  var lResource = $resource("rest/blogpost/:blogId/:allInfo");
    lResource.query({});
    lResource.query({blogId:123});
    lResource.query({blogId:123,allInfo:'allInfo'});
```

See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/NnHr4/1/ ( See Console log)

Comment: Ye right now I'm using this solution and this still leaves a slash after blogId if allInfo isn't passed to the resource

Comment: When i see it in console log it does not. This is what i see http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/rest/blogpost/123